# How to list files without directories, and filter by name (ls options)

Tags: ls, filenames

I have a directory called `uploads`. It contains a bunch of files, plus a few subdirectories which in turn contain files.

Is there a way I can (in one step) do the following:

1. List ONLY the files in the root uploads directory -- I do not want to see the subfolder names or their contents;

   **and**
2. Do NOT list any files that start with `t_`

I know about the `-d` flag, but it doesn't get me quite what I want.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This sounds like a job for `find`.

- Use `-maxdepth` to only return the current directory, not recursivly search inside subfolders
- Use `-type f` to only return files and not directories or device nodes or whatever else
- Use a combination if `-not` and `-name` to avoid the files with names you don't want

It might come together like this:

```
find /path/to/uploads -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -name 't_*'
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm pretty new to CLI and had never used find before. I'll definitely look further into it.

Comment: @EmmyS: You might find one more little trick useful here. @Gilles mentioned using `-exec ls -lG -- {} +` in his answer to get the output using extra options to ls. You can also add just an `-ls` to this find to get a quick and dirty approximation of ls's detailed view.

Answer (score 20):

GNU ls (i.e. the ls command on non-embedded Linux systems and Cygwin, also available on some other unices) has an option to hide some files, based on their names. There's no way to ignore directories though.

```
ls --hide='t_*' uploads
```

Another approach is to make your shell do the matching. Bash, ksh and zsh have a negation pattern `!(t_*)` to match all files except those matching `t*`; in bash this feature needs to be turned on with `shopt -s extglob`, and in zsh it needs to be turned on with `setopt ksh_glob`. Zsh also has the equivalent syntax `^t_*` which needs to be turned on with `setopt extended_glob`. This still doesn't ignore directories. Zsh has an extra feature that allows to match files not only by name but also by metadata and more: [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers). Add `(.)` at the end of a match to restrict to regular files. The negation `^` is part of the name matching syntax, so `^t_*(.)` means “all regular files not matching `t_*`” and not “all files that aren't regular files matching `t_*`”.

```
setopt extended_glob  # put this in your ~/.zshrc
ls uploads/^t_*(.)
```

If you find yourself without advanced tools, you can do this on any unix with `find`. It's not the kind of thing you'd typically type on the command line, but it's powerful and precise. [Caleb has already shown how to do this with GNU find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15950/how-to-list-files-without-directories-and-filter-by-name-ls-options/15951#15951). The `-maxdepth` option isn't portable; you can use `-prune` instead, to portably stop `find` from recursing.

```
find uploads/* -type d -prune -o \! -type f -name 't_*' -print
```

Replace `-print` by `-exec ls -lG -- {} +` to execute `ls` with your favorite options on the files.

All the commands above hide dot files (i.e. files whose name begins with a `.`). If you want to display them, pass `-A` to `ls`, or add the `D` glob qualifier in zsh (`ls uploads/^t_*(.D)`). With `find`, you can use a different approach of making it recurse one level only (`find` doesn't treat dot files specially). This only fully works if you run `find` in the current directory.

```
cd uploads && find . -name . -o -type d -prune -o \! -type f -name 't_*' -print
```

Comment: Do you have a dayjob? ;-)  I'm constantly amazed at the length and level of details of your answers, even to the simplest looking questions here at Unix SE!..  Keep that up anyway! :)

Comment: Thanks! Great detail. I don't know if I have "advanced tools" or not right now; I'm on a Mac at work (although Linux at home, so I'm sure this will come in handy at some point.)

Comment: @EmmyS: For your linux box my use of `-maxdepth` should work, but the "portability" problem Gilles refers to is that the BSD `find` (also found on OSX I think) is a bit different animal, so you might need his answer too. @Gilles: +1 for the zsh trick!

Comment: @Caleb, in this case, find with maxdepth produced just what I needed on the Mac (at least, as far as I can tell - there are several thousand files, so I can't go through it line by line.)

Comment: @EmmyS: You're quite right, BSD find on OSX has `-maxdepth`, I just checked one here. @Gilles: To which versions of find is this not portable?

Comment: @Caleb It's not in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) (I normally define portable as [POSIX:2004](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html)). [AIX](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds2/find.htm), [Solaris](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19963-01/html/821-1461/find-1.html) don't have it. But all the BSDs (Free, Open, Net, OSX) have it. It's in Busybox too, but not in [MINIX3](http://www.minix3.org/manpages/man1/find.1.html).

Comment: @Gilles: Some not so juicy comments about `prune`s come to mind, but I'll let it go by simply saying that when I'm mucking around on my own systems the number of times the thought "*would this command work if I was on AIX, Solaris or MINIX3*" is approximately ... standby ... I'm having a hard time getting a meter reading ... the display is frozen with `0.00`.

Comment: Doesn't Gnu `ls` have a `--use-telepathy` option? That's the quickest way to display just the files you want. It might not be portable though.

Comment: @dubiousjim [Telepathy has `ls`](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/freedesktop/telepathy/idle/tools/ls-interfaces.xsl) but not the other way round. Maybe GNU could port the [time travel feature of Emacs](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/astaff/source/src-8.1/third/emacs/etc/future-bug) to `ls`, so that it already knows which file you will act on with your next commands and only displays that one.

Comment: Time travel might be overkill. Wouldn't it be enough to use a shell that can capture continuations. (Bounded by the session, not the prompt.) We might see an uptick in "I don't understand my shell!" questions though.

Answer (score 11):

```
ls -l /folder | grep ^- | awk '{print $9}'
```

Comment: What is `$9` in this statement?

Comment: @EmmyS It means the 9th field / column of the output.  This answer is trying to [parse `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: `print `$NF` would be more betterer, IMO. $NF means number of fields, which would be 9 and is a common usage in AWK as good opportunity to teach others about $NF.

Comment: @ElijahLynn "More betterer" made my day, I did not know the expression :D

Answer (score 2):

```
ls -l | grep -v ^d | grep name$
```

Comment: What would make this solution (which requires multiple commands and pipes) preferable to `find`?

Comment: It is concise, easy to read and stays with the ls command convention. I find it easier to remember than the find command arguments. To each their own and kudos for options!

Answer (score 1):

I found these short ways:

```
ls -p uploads | grep -Ev '/'
```

or

```
ls -pIt_* uploads | grep -v /
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me give it a shot using `ls` and pipes:

```
ls  -l --hide='t_*'  uploads/ | grep -v ^d | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 9
```

say last column is the 9th one.

Comment: What if there are files with spaces?

Answer (score 0):

If find's -maxdepth portability issue is a concern, you could use:

```
ls -l uploads/ | awk '/^-/ && $9 !~/^t_/ {print $9}'
```

I'm not an expert, but I think this should work. I suppose it looks a little cryptic, but if you speak awk, it's really not. $NF could be used instead of $9. You could also do:

```
ls -l uploads/ | awk '/^-/' | awk '!/^t_/ {print $9}'
```

which does the same thing (but perhaps less efficiently than the former ???).

Actually, after thinking about the other posts, it looks like

```
ls -l --hide=t_* uploads/ | awk '/^-/ {print $9}'
```

is an even shorter and clearer way.

Someone please correct me if I'm wrong. :-)

Comment: [Parsing `ls` is generally not a good idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Your awk tricks will fail with filenames with whitespace in them for instance.

Comment: @mat -- Thank you for the correction. After reading the article that you (and jw013) pointed out, I see that **ls** cannot be trusted to output correct file names. Even if I were to rewrite the awk code to print everything from $9 to the end of the line (to include whitespaces), this **ls** output may still be erroneous. This is disappointing and should be corrected IMO. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Try this alias and use it:

```
alias l='ls -hLlF'
```

Comment: `ls -hLlF` does show the subdirectories and it does show the files starting with `t_`. So how does this answer the question?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the question. 
ls -hLlF
will not show the target directories of linked directories.

Comment: Seems so. But haven't you read the other answers for the question?

Answer (score -1):

Easy peasy:

`ls -l --hide 't_*' <absolute path to desired directory> | grep -v ^d`

Comment: (1) This answer is so easy, it’s been given before.  (2) Why do you believe that you need to specify the full path to the directory?

Comment: @Scott - this is a very quick and simple way to get to the solution.  The full path was specified to make the answer universal...