# why does ls -d also list files, and where is it documented?

Tags: bash, shell, ls, wildcards, options

- when specifying `ls --directory a*` it should list only directories starting with `a*`
- BUT it lists files AND directories starting with `a`

**Questions**:

- where might I find some documentation on this, other than `man` and `info` where I think I thoroughly looked?
- does this work in BASH only?

Comment: See also [this other very similar question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/62660/22565).

Comment: `echo a*` will also list you the files starting with `a` (if any). Just to make it more clear that it's not `ls` doing this but the bash.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The `a*` and `*a*` syntax is implemented by the shell, not by the `ls` command.

When you type

```
ls a*
```

at your shell prompt, the shell expands `a*` to a list of existing all files in the current directory whose names start with `a`. For example, it might expand `a*` to the sequence `a1 a2 a3`, and pass those as arguments to `ls`. The `ls` command itself never sees the `*` character; it only sees the three arguments `a1`, `a2`, and `a3`.

For purposes of wildcard expansion, "files" refers to all entities in the current directory. For example, `a1` might be a normal file, `a2` might be a directory, and `a3` might be a symlink. They all have directory entries, and the shell's wildcard expansion doesn't care what kind of entity those entries refer to.

Practically all shells you're likely to run across (bash, sh, ksh, zsh, csh, tcsh, ...) implement wildcards. The details may vary, but the basic syntax of `*` matching zero or more characters and `?` matching any single character is reasonably consistent.

For bash in particular, this is documented in the "Filename expansion" section of the bash manual; run `info bash` and search for "Filename expansion", or see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html).

The fact that this is done by the shell, and not by individual commands, has some interesting (and sometimes surprising) consequences.  The best thing about it is that wildcard handling is consistent for (very nearly) *all* commands; if the shell didn't do this, inevitably some commands wouldn't bother, and others would do it in subtly different ways that the author thought was "better". (I think the Windows command shell has this problem, but I'm not familiar enough with it to comment further.)

On the other hand, it's difficult to write a command to rename multiple files. If you write:

```
mv *.log *.log.bak
```

it will probably fail, since`*.log.bak` is expanded based on the files that already exist in the current directory. There are commands that do this kind of thing, but they have to use their own syntax to specify how the files are to be renamed. Some commands (such as `find`) can do their own wildcard expansion; you have to quote the arguments to suppress the shell's expansion:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -print
```

The shell's wildcard expansion is based entirely on the syntax of the command-line argument and the set of existing files. It *can't* be affected by the meaning of the command. For example, if you want to move all `.log` files up to the parent directory, you can type:

```
mv *.log ..
```

If you forget the `..` :

```
mv *.log
```

and there happen to be exactly two `.log` files in the current directory, it will expand to:

```
mv one.log two.log
```

which will rename `one.log` and clobber `two.log`.

**EDIT**: And after 52 upvotes, an accept, and a Guru badge, maybe I should actually answer the question in the title.

The `-d` or `--directory` option to `ls` doesn't tell it to list only directories. It tells it to list directories just as themselves, not their contents. If you give a directory name as an argument to `ls`, by default it will list the *contents* of the directory, since that's usually what you're interested in. The `-d` option tells it to list just the directory itself. This can be particularly useful when combined with wildcards. If you type:

```
ls -l a*
```

`ls` will give you a long listing of each *file* whose name starts with `a`, and of the *contents* of each directory whose name starts with `a`. If you just want a list of the files and directories, one line for each, you can use:

```
ls -ld a*
```

which is equivalent to:

```
ls -l -d a*
```

Remember again that the `ls` command never sees the `*` character.

As for where this is documented, `man ls` will show you the documentation for the `ls` command on just about any Unix-like system. On most Linux-based systems, the `ls` command is part of the GNU coreutils package; if you have the `info` command, either `info ls` or `info coreutils ls` should give you more definitive and comprehensive documentation. Other systems, such as MacOS, may use different versions of the `ls` command, and may not have the `info` command; for those systems, use `man ls`. And `ls --help` will show a *relatively* short usage message (117 lines on my system) *if* you're using the GNU coreutils implementation.

And yes, even experts need to consult the documentation now and then. See also [this classic joke](http://www.netfunny.com/rhf/jokes/91q3/ieeee.html).

Comment: But how can this work? Since `a*` maps to all files starting with "a", doesn't this mean you'd need to expand `a*` to infinitely many possible arguments? Or does it limit itself to the files that would otherwise be processed by `ls`?

Comment: @Thomas: `a*` expands to a list of all files *in the current directory* whose names start with `a`.

Comment: So pattern matching applies to files in the current directory only. Thanks, that makes more sense.

Comment: @Thomas: Or in whatever directory you specify:`ls subdir/a*`

Comment: The `zsh` shell has more powerful wildcarding options.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks. I thought you meant the shell performed general purpose wildcarding, and was confused since if it's the shell doing the replacing then it shouldn't care that `ls` (file enumeration tool) is the program being called. But as wildcards are for files only, I understand now.

Comment: To really see the command executed after the shell expansion, `echo` it. So if you want to know what is happening when you do `ls a*`, first execute `echo ls a*`

Comment: or just `echo a*` ... the shell does glob expansion anyway

Comment: and if glob pattern matched nothing, it is passed 'as is' to the command.

Comment: @sendmoreinfo: That depends on the shell and the settings. In csh and tcsh, a failing glob expansion is an error. In bash, `shopt -s failglob` causes the same behavior. Setting `nullglob` but not `failglob` causes, for example, `*nosuchfile*` to expand to an empty string.

Comment: Thanks for the good info! The part about `mv` and `*.log` is very interesting.

Comment: @KeithThompson and if my limited experience (10 minutes setting it up) with `zsh` is correct, you can set an option to throw an error with a failed glob expansion

Answer (score 27):

See Keith Thompson’s answer; but to explain why `ls --directory a*` shows files *and* directories: The `--directory` option does not suppress non-directory files. Instead, it lists the directories as such, while it would otherwise list their content. Example:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ touch foo/bar
$ ls foo
bar
$ ls --directory foo
foo
```

Comment: that example is more compelling with the `-F` option

Answer (score 6):

To be very explicit, it is documented in the [ls(1) manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ls):

**-d, --directory**
list directory entries instead of contents, and do not dereference symbolic links

to be fair, "entries instead of contents" could probably be more explanatory:

> If FILE is a directory, show the directory entry itself instead of listing the contents of that directory. If FILE is a symbolic link, show the link entry itself instead of the file pointed to by the link.

Comment: To be pedantic, while the -d option may be explained (if tersely) in the man page, argument expansion and wildcarding is not documented in the ls man page since it's done by the shell. If you turned off filename expansion in your shell, "ls a*" would only show you a file that's literally named 'a*'.

Comment: To be pedantic, while shell expansion was answered by other respondents, none of them addresses the scant explanation and how it might be misread. If you should like me to repeat that which was already well said, please be more direct.

Answer (score 4):

## Globbing

As has been explained, the expansion of `*` (and similar expansions) is called `glob`bing in Unix jargon, and is usually a feature of the command processor (known as the "shell" in Unix parlance). So globbing can be used in many other places too; type `man 7 glob` at the shell of a classic Linux distribution (or see [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html)) for more about `glob`bing.

In early Unix, `glob` was actually implemented by a [separate program](http://unix-jun72.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/cmd/glob.c) called `/etc/glob` (see page 10 of [this old UNIX manual](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/man71.pdf) for documentation for that). Nowadays, it is a code routine supplied by code libraries, and is commonly used by shells. **Source**: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29#Origin).

## Directories

As to why `ls -d` lists files as well as directories...

The [`ls` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) explains why this happens, but with a very terse explanation. So here is an attempt at an expanded explanation:

By default `ls` lists the *contents* of directories when given their names, and will do the same thing for *symlinks* to directories. The `-d` option means, *"when given name(s) of directory(ies)" (which can also be given *implicitly* by `glob`bing)*, only show the _name_s of the directory(ies), but *not* their contents. Similarly, when provided with (explicitly or *implicitly*) name(s) of symlinks to *directories*, show the file name of the symlink, not the contents of the directory which it references.

The `-d` option has nothing to do, as far as I can tell, with *which* items are listed; this can be done (source: [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15950/how-to-list-files-without-directories-and-filter-by-name-ls-options)) with `find`, like so: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d`. I am not sure if there is a good way to do so only with GNU `ls`. [Here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html#EXAMPLES) are some examples of how to use the `find` command.

So to sum up: By default `ls` shows the contents of directories when given their path name. `-d` changes this behavior, only showing the directory name itself, as would be done for a standard file.

Answer (score 3):

Documentation doesn't say it lists *only* directory entries bur rather when `ls` receives directory name it lists dir entry *instead of* it's content. Best way to understand is by example:

```
> {ice} ~ :10:47 % ls -l / 
total 97
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 May  3 00:27 bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  1024 May  3 14:17 boot
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 29 13:44 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x  18 root root  4420 May  9 09:58 dev
...
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    33 May  3 14:16 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-3.9.0-030900-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    29 May  3 11:07 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic
> {ice} ~ :10:47 % ls -ld /
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root 4096 May  3 14:16 /
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is part of the *shell*. In particular the shell performs various **expansions and substitutions** in a particular order before executing a command.

The sequence of [*word expansions* for a Bourne compatible shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06) is

1. Tilde Expansion
2. Parameter Expansion
3. Command Substitution
4. Arithmetic Expansion
5. Field Splitting
6. Pathname Expansion
7. Quote Removal

So, the `ls` command doesn't even see the `*` characters, the arguments are already expanded with all files matching the `a*` glob pattern. This is unlike on Windows, where each command needing file name globbing has to implement this feature itself.

Answer (score 1):

The key word you need (`man bash`) is "Pathname Expansion".

Comment: more like "Pathname Expansion" or "Filename Generation". Related to "pattern matching", but not the same.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Indeed, but "pattern matching" is a subsection of "pathname expansion" in the man page whereas "Filename Generation" doesn't occur there at all (just in the info document).