# Why `ls -d` only demonstrate `.`?

Tags: directory, ls

I'd like to only the directory

```
$ ls -d 
.
#get . on macos
```

and the same on centos

```
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z ~]# ls -d .
.
```

I find the solution:

```
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z /]# ls -d */
bin/   dev/  home/  lib64/       media/  opt/   root/  sbin/  sys/  usr/
boot/  etc/  lib/   lost+found/  mnt/    proc/  run/   srv/   tmp/  var/
```

but the manual specify

```
   -d, --directory
          list directories themselves, not their contents
```

What's the reason `-d` perform this way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why does ls -d also list files, and where is it documented?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75046/why-does-ls-d-also-list-files-and-where-is-it-documented)

Answer (score 1):

`ls -d` applies to "this" directory, not to the directories contained in the location where you are running `ls`.

It seems odd if you're just running `ls -d` but if you want to know, say, who owns this directory, you could do `ls -do` and see only the owner of the current directory.

There's a much more comprehensive explanation included in the answer to [why does ls -d also list files, and where is it documented?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75046/why-does-ls-d-also-list-files-and-where-is-it-documented/75047#75047)

And a lot of good insight at [The result of ls * , ls ** and ls ***](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62660/the-result-of-ls-ls-and-ls) if you really want to go deep on `ls`

Comment: `*` vs `**` is mostly about the expansions the shell supports, not about `ls` specifically, even though `ls` is used there in that question.

Answer (score 0):

The `ls` utility lists the pathname arguments given on its command line.  If any of the arguments corresponds to a *directory*, then the complete contents of that directory will be displayed.   If no argument is given, then `ls` lists the current directory, as if `ls .` was used.

To be able to list a directory (to see the directory entry for a directory), not its contents, you have the `-d` option of `ls`.  With it, you can say `ls -d dir` and get the directory entry for `dir` and not its contents.

The reason `ls -d` by itself only returns a dot (the current directory) is that it's essentially the same as `ls -d .`, i.e. "give me the directory entry for the current directory without showing its contents".

---

What your `ls -d */` command is doing is showing the directory entries for all directories in the current directory that does not have hidden names.  You only get *directories* due to the `/` at the end of the pattern. Since you use `-d`, you don't get the contents of these directories.

Comment: @AdwaitUpadhyay Thanks for your suggested edit, but `ls -d */` only shows directories because of the trailing `/` at the end of the pattern.  Yes, `ls -d *` also shows directories, but it shows non-directories too, and it's furthermore not the command the user in the question is using in their example.